Neovim: Is there any way to silence lsp/diagnostics messages by regex?
Jumping to the solution, I know, apologies.
Context: I work on a large Django code base where mypy is too slow to be usable, so I use pyright, which is fast enough but can't handle some of the Django magic (django-stubs is the normal fix for this but the relevant part is implemented as _mypy_ plugin so won't work for pyright)
e.g.:
Cannot access member "applications" for type "Account" Pyright (reportAttributeAccessIssue) [58, 24]

(because .applications is a custom queryset attribute and pyright can't pick up on those)
So I'd like to silence a subset of pyright warnings.  I don't want to silence the general reportAttributeAccessIssue because that would catch too many valid errors. And I don't want to fill my codebase with type: ignores, because CI (and other devs) use mypy, pyright is a personal choice and i want a personal solution that doesn't affect others.
Instead I'm happy to maintain a list of regexes to catch eg the specific querysets and model names i know of.
So, is there a way to silence lsp / vim diagnostic errors using a regex?
Also interested in other bright ideas if you have them!
I'm using lsp-zero and mason-lspconfig, if that's relevant.
[edit 2024-11-08] thanks to @eyal-karni who suggested https://github.com/m-gail/diagnostic_manipulation.nvim - exactly what i want!

You would disable pyright checks the same way you'd always do that. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335636/is-it-possible-to-ignore-pyright-checking-for-one-line Your question has nothing to do with Vim. I'm voting to close as off-topic.

I don't think that the LSP bridge as a way to filter out some warnings or errors. The best would be to filter them our from the source (i.e. from pyright) like @Friedrich suggested.

thanks Friedrich, Vivian, i don't want to fill my code with type: ignores tho. will clarify in the q.

I'd argue it's the reasonable approach to comment where code does not live up to a linting rule. Anyhow, it seems you can also put exceptions in a pyrightconfig.json file.

I understand but as said I doubt that the functionality you would like to have in the LSP bridge already exist. If nobody come with a suggestion I suppose you have to ask for a new functionality in the LSP bridge that you are using (it is probably the Neovim LSP builtin bridge).

Or propose to add the filtering functionality to the pyright configuration. I believe you'll have slightly more chance that way (Neovim people have a lot of work that probably have higher priority :-|).

@Friedrich I couldn't see anything in the pyright config that would let you disable things at the level of granularity that I'm looking for - maybe I missed something?

What I do is that I fill location list with the diagnostics and filter it using cfilter (default package)
You need to run
packadd cfilter
first.
nnoremap <leader>XD <CMD>lua vim.diagnostic.setloclist()<CR>

"check file
nnoremap <leader>xf <CMD>lua vim.diagnostic.setloclist()<CR><CMD>Lfilter /syntax\\|is not defined/<CR>


If you want to be more methodical, you might filter the diagnostics  in lua at a certain event (using autocmd). If you print the table of diagnostics, you will see how to do it.
But I do agree with @Vivan that ideally it should be done in the lsp bridge.
UPDATE:
Someone wrote such plugin
https://github.com/m-gail/diagnostic_manipulation.nvim/tree/main
The code below works(Lazy.nvim) :
        {
            "m-gail/diagnostic_manipulation.nvim",
            event = "VeryLazy",
            init = function ()
                require("diagnostic_manipulation").setup {
                    blacklist = {
                        function(diagnostic)
                            return string.find(diagnostic.message, "Undefined global `vim`")
                        end
                        --require("diagnostic_manipulation.builtin.tsserver").tsserver_codes({ 6133, 6196 })
                    },
                    whitelist = {
                        -- Your whitelist here
                    }
                }
            end
        },




oo diagnostic_manipulation.nvim looks like exactly what I want, THANK YOU
